# difference of use comma or semicomma

Tags: javascript

I have question concerning the difference of using in JavaScript code `comma` OR `semicolon`.

Do they have differences and influence how the code works?

In the code below I changed the semicolon after definition of var `fib` that have value `0` by comma an code didn't run.

Can somebody explain this?

The full code of Fibonacci in which it has occurred is here:

```
<script>
    document.write("<h2>Числа Фибоначчи </h2>");
    for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 0, fib = 0; i < 50; i++, fib = j + k, j = k, k = fib) {
        document.write("Fibonacci (" + i + ") = " + fib);
        document.write("<br>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a typical syntax of `for`-loop statements in JavaScript.

Comment: Really? Same question was asked here yesterday

Comment: @VisioN, I wouldn't  call it *typical*.

Comment: @gdoron You don't think that `var a = 1, b = 2;` is typical for javascript? At least very common.

Comment: @dfsq The comma in `var` is a different kind of comma.

Comment: Your code should be working, see http://jsfiddle.net/FfKRv/. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @dfsq common for sure. I use this all the time. it saves space

Answer (score 0):

[for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) encloses 3 expressions :

- the initialization (run before the loop),
- the end of loop test (run before each iteration),
- and the after iteration statement.

Statements in javascript are separated by `;`. If you change the `;` to a  `,`, you don't end the init statement.

Comment: Commas separate arguments to a statement. Semicolons separate statements

Answer (score 0):

The part that probably confuses you is the fact that a 'normal' for-loop takes three statements like the following:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
  x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
```

but that your example substitutes these expressions with comma seperated arguments.

`var i=0` -> `i = 0, j = 1, k = 0, fib = 0`

`i++` -> `i++, fib = j + k, j = k, k = fib`

BTW, this is terrible code that reads very hard and is even harder to maintain. **Don't use it.**

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are indeed correct, but I think this is not about the `for` - it is about the comma, which is in fact an operator:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.
>   - [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

If you want to learn more about it: Angus C. elaborately explains what it does in his [blog](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/).